# Изменение класса элемента при изменении разрешения экрана

Tags: экран, адаптивная-верстка, css, javascript

Ребята, всем привет!

Занимаюсь версткой проекта, адаптивного, и потребовалось сделать так, чтобы при разрешении экрана менее 700 пикселей, у одного элемента менялся класс (при этом у него задано 2 класса, что-то типа: class="one two").

Изменить нужно именно второй класс "two".
Через [@media](/users/3055/mediaportal) - не вариант, мне конкретно нужно присвоить новый класс элементу.

Понимаю, что это нужно сделать средствами js, но как - ума не приложу.

Очень буду рад за подсказку!
Понимаю, что вопрос нубовский, но очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Comment: Кажется, если присваивать переменной другой класс, первый из памяти удаляться не будет, а так и останется висеть. Если они задают прорисовку объектов, может случиться так, что отрисованные элементы останутся на экране. Блок if()else в данном случае точно не проходит?

Comment: Тогда присвойте еще класс three - class="one two three" - последний третий класс не используйте до 700 - а когда нужно, используйте @media менее 700 используйте этот третий класс. Может, это поможет?

Answer (score 1):

В JavaScript невозможно вычислить ширину так же, как это делается с помощью media-queries в CSS.  
Однако есть хитрый способ обойти это ограничение.
Можно транслировать текущий порог ширины экрана в качестве css-свойства для невидимого элемента, например, `head`, а в javascript читать значение этого свойства.

CSS

```
/* @media трансляторы для javascript */
@media (min-width: 320px) {
    head {
        width: 320px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
    head {
        width: 480px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    head {
        width: 700px;
    }
}
```

Чтобы было честно, написал на чистом javascript.

```
window.load = function(){
    // Теперь мы знаем актуальную ширину экрана
    var media_size = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.head, null)
                                    .getPropertyValue('width'), 10);

    switchClass();

    window.resize = function () {
        // Обновляем ширину экрана
        media_size = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.head, null)
                                    .getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
        switchClass();
    };
};

function switchClass() {
    if(media_size  < 700) {
        // ...
    }
    else{
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно и на джеквери:

```
function myFunction() {
    if($(window).width() < 700)
    {   
        Если ширина меньше делаем это
    }
    else
    {
        Если больше это
    }
}

//вызываем
myFunction();

//ну и при ресайзе перепроверяем
$(window).resize(function() {
    myFunction();
});
```